# Adding a WordPress filter in a class/spacename

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have a main plugin and a sub-plugin. The function of the sub-plugin is to extract information from a 3rd-party plugin and pass it to the main plugin.

Extracting the information is no problem, and I can pass hardcoded information through a filter.
But when I try to make the filter dynamic, it stops functioning.

What's the best approch for this situation?

Main plugin uses this code:

```
namespace Essif\Testing
class Hooks extends Flow
    public static function options(): array {
        $res = apply_filters('custom_filter_testing', '');
        return $res;
    }
```

My subplugin looks like this:

```
public function getTarget() {
    return ['foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar'];
}

    public function essif_hook_data()
    {
        $context = ['CF7' => 'CF7'];
        $target = ['foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar'];
        //$target = $this->getTarget();
        $res = ['context' => $context, 'target' => $target];
        return $res;
    }
```

Using hardcoded info, it works. But if I use $this->getTarget(), it throws an error.

EDIT:
Errors:
ManageHooks::options() must be of the type array, string returned
$this
Using $this when not in object context

Comment: "it throws an error" - what error?

Comment: Using $this when not in object context @naththedeveloper